# Scraping data with HTML and VBA

Tags: html, vba

Today I'm trying to be lazy and to compare electricity providers as I'm moving.
The [website is here](https://comparateur.selectra.info/fournisseurs/alterna/electricite#offres) for those interested, though I'll link the code that interests me just below.

I've already managed to go through each provider and get its information page, but its once I'm there that things go rough. On the info page, offers are listed on cards with the class "card card-offer  ".
I manage to go through each card but not get the data I want.

Here is a tidied up version of the HTML code.

```html
<article class="card card-offer  ">
  <div class="offer-body">
    <h3 class="offer-name">
      Idéa Elec <span class="offer-type-large">
                                                                      </span>
    </h3>
    <div class="offer-provider">

    </div>
    <div class="offer-advantages">

    </div>
    <div class="offer-type-small">

    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="offer-cta">
    <div class="offer-buttons">

    </div>

    <div class="offer-figure " data-id="48" data-totalvotes="5" data-idprovider="19">
      <div class="figure-text">
        <div class="offer-savings ">
        </div>

        <div class="offer-budget">
          Budget :<strong> 2208€<span>/an</span></strong>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</article>
```

The data I'm trying to get here is :

- the "offer-name", here Idéa Elec
- the "offer-budget", here 2208€

I thought about going at it with tags, but it seems all the pages have the same classes but the tags are not arranged in the same order, breaking my code at one point. It works but only for a limited amount of cases
I then decided to take a go by going through classes but cannot manage to do it.
Here is my code.

```
Public Sub parsehtmlelec()

Dim http As Object, html As New HTMLDocument, offers As Object, offElem As Object, detailsElem As Object, offer As HTMLHtmlElement
Dim i, j As Integer
Dim site As String

For j = 1 To Range("FournisseursElec").Rows.Count

'That's my table where I get the websites to parse through

    site = Range("FournisseursElec[Site interne Selectra]")(j)

    Set http = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")

    http.Open "GET", site, False
    http.send
    html.body.innerHTML = http.responseText

    Set offers = html.getElementsByClassName("card card-offer  ")

    For Each offer In offers

        'Here's here I try to get the offer name

        Range("OffresElec[Fournisseur]")(i).Value = Range("FournisseursElec[Fournisseur]")(j)

        Set offElem = offer.getElementsByClassName("offer-body")(0).getElementsByClassName("offer-name")(0)

        Range("OffresElec[Nom de l'offre]")(i).Value = offElem.innerText

        'Here's here I try to get the offer savings

        Set detailsElem = offer.getElementsByClassName("offer-cta")(0).getElementsByClassName("offer-figure")(0).getElementsByClassName("figure-text")(0).getElementsByClassName("offer-budget")(0).getElementsByTagName("strong")(0)

        Range("OffresElec[Budget annuel]")(i).Value = detailsElem.innerText

        i = i + 1

    Next

Next j

End Sub
```

Do you know what's going wrong here ? I can't seem to grasp how to get the text in the elements...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this. It will fetch the data you wish to get:

```
Sub Web_Data()
    Dim http As New XMLHTTP60, html As New HTMLDocument
    Dim topic As HTMLHtmlElement

    With http
        .Open "GET", "https://comparateur.selectra.info/fournisseurs/alterna/electricite#offres", False
        .send
        html.body.innerHTML = .responseText
    End With

    For Each topic In html.getElementsByClassName("card card-offer")
        row = row + 1: Cells(row, 1) = topic.getElementsByClassName("offer-name")(0).innerText
        Cells(row, 2) = Split(topic.getElementsByClassName("offer-budget")(0).innerText, "Budget : ")(1)
    Next topic
End Sub
```

Output:

```
Idéa Elec   2208€/an 
Idéa Vert   2336€/an
```

Reference to add to the library:

```
1. Microsoft XML, v6.0
2. Microsoft HTML Object Library
```

Comment: Thank you !
Your code works by itself but in replacing with my table, it suddenly failed.

I realized that the " ' " character is not just but should be doubled for it to be a valid reference ! You made me realize that and I know why I scratched my head now :)
And of course, your code is quite prettier than mine !